# Where is Illuminate?

Tags: php, laravel

Every time when I try to do some modifications in certain area, *Authentication for example*, I end up finding everything is declared in `Illuminate\Foundation\...`.

Okay, now all I need to do is get to that location and look into some codes.

But hey, where is this `Illuminate` and all stuff???

I don't see any folders named Illuminate anywhere in my Laravel package.

Tried to search for the solution but I guess I'm the only silly person who lacks ability in understanding some basics.

Comment: It's all inside your vendors folder. What are you trying to edit exactly? The issue with editing vendor files directly is that your changes are overwritten when the package updates.

Comment: @James - Wow, found what I wanted! I'm not trying to edit directly, I need to understand logics behind so that I can do something else in acceptable ways. Thanks bunch!!!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Just to officially answer this question.

The files OP was looking for, along with any other Laravel or package files, are stored in the vendor folder - which you can access from the root Laravel directory.

As @Gavin points out in the comments:

> Illuminate is located in /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate

Comment: Illuminate is located in `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate`.

Comment: more accurately, `Illuminate` is a laravel root namespace which follows PSR-4 recommendation

Comment: how we can get illuminate/support version? @james

Answer (score 9):

Laravel take the advantage of the autoload features in Composer.

One quick and simple tips:

You can actually find this in `composer.lock` file. Then find the PSR autoload. For instance, for `Laravel/framework`:

```
       {
        "name" : "laravel/framework",
        .......
        .......
        "autoload": {
            "classmap": [
                "src/Illuminate/Queue/IlluminateQueueClosure.php"
            ],
            "files": [
                "src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php",
                "src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php"
            ],
            "psr-4": {
                "Illuminate\\": "src/Illuminate/"
            }
        }
       }
```

Since there are a lot of packages in `vendor` folder, refer the name of the package in the composer.lock. For example, Illuminate is under `laravel/framework` packages. Then, look for `vendor/laravel/framework`

Then you know, `Illuminate` is mapped to `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate`